# Can the integral containing a logarithm be extended to complex values $m$ and $n$?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, gamma-function

Consider the integral $$I(m,n):=\int_0^1 \ln^m(x)x^n dx$$

With the definition of the gamma-function, I worked out that

$$I(m,n)=\frac{(-1)^mm!}{(n+1)^{m+1}}$$

for $m,n\ge 0$. With the definitions $m!:=\Gamma(m+1)$ and $(-1)^m:=e^{i\pi m}$, the formula seems to be correct even for real non-negative $m,n$.

> Questions :
>
> - Is the formula actually correct for all non-negative real $m,n$ ?
> - Can the formula be extended for complex numbers $m,n$ , assuming $\Gamma(m+1)$ is defined and $n\ne -1$ ? If not, for which complex values $m,n$ does the given formula hold and for which complex $m,n$ does the integral exist ?

Comment: Non-integer powers aren't terribly well-defined, this is the root of many issues in complex analysis.

Comment: Consider the change of variables $x=e^y$ and consider the real valued exponents $\alpha$ and $\beta$
$$
I_{\alpha,\beta}=\int_{-\infty}^0y^{\alpha-1}e^{\beta y}
$$

which converges for $\alpha>0 \, ,\beta>0$. Now choosing the branch of $\log$ to lie on the negative real axis this equals


$$
I_{\alpha,\beta}=\frac{(-1)^{\alpha}}{\beta^{\alpha}}\int_0^{\infty}y^{\alpha-1}e^{- y}=\frac{(-1)^{\alpha}}{\beta^{\alpha}}\Gamma(\alpha)
$$

which might be analytically continued into the complex parameter manifold $\mathbb{C}^2/\{\alpha\notin\mathbb{Z}_-,\beta\neq0\}$